# C++: multimap custom comparator for object keys

Tags: c++, comparator, multimap

Can I somehow use my own function for ordering the pairs in multimap? I have three classes CTimeStamp, CMail and CMailLog. And the thing is in the CMailLog I have 
`multimap<CTimeStamp, CMail>` which I use because for this task I need solution which will be very fast for huge amounts of data and therefor I would need to somehow use method Compare from CTimeStamp when inserting into this multimap. The classes look something like this.

```
class CTimeStamp {
   public:
     int compare (const CTimeStamp &x) const;
     ...
}
class CMail {
   ...
}
class CMailLog {
   public:
     ...
   private:
     multimap<CTimeStamp, CMail> logs;
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would need to somehow use method Compare from `CTimeStamp` when inserting into this multimap

As from the [`std::multimap` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap), all you need is to either

- provide a specialisation for `std::less<CTimeStamp>`

  ```
  namespace std {
      bool less<CTimeStamp>(const CTimeStamp& a, const CTimeStamp& b) {
          return a.compare(b) < 0;
      }
  }
  ```

or

- provide a custom comparator at the constructor:

  ```
  CMailLog() : 
      logs([](const CTimeStamp& a, const CTimeStamp& b) { return a.compare(b) < 0; }) 
  {}
  ```

---

I used a *lambda expression* in my last example for the constructor as I consider that's the shortest and most comprehensible form.
In fact ***any callable*** with the signature `bool (const CTimeStamp&,const CTimeStamp&)` would fit well.

You might also write a simple global function

```
bool foo(const CTimeStamp& a,const CTimeStamp& b) {
    return a.compare(b) < 0;
}
```

or appropriate callable type

```
struct foo {
    bool operator()(const CTimeStamp& a,const CTimeStamp& b) {
        return a.compare(b) < 0;
    }
};
```

and pass that one at the

```
multimap<CTimeStamp, CMail> logs;
```

in the constructor initializer list:

```
CMailLog() : logs(foo) {}
```

Callable struct version

```
CMailLog() : logs(foo()) {}
```